# Search library dependency in android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

After updating to Android Strudio 3.0, I tried adding a library from

> project structure -> dependencies -> add library

, but searching doesn't seems to work, nothing is found. 
   My `build.gradle` file looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: See my answer there, it helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222905/android-studio-3-does-not-search-for-libraries-dependencies/49516430#49516430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems only the libraries in com.android.xx and com.google.xx package can be searched.