# Android studio 3 does not search for libraries dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

My Android studio stopped searching for library dependencies. I know that it's better and faster to add dependencies through build.gradle but sometimes it's easier to search from inner search window of android studio than googling it. For example, this is how retrofit search results looks like[image]

This bug appeared after upgrade to Android studio 3

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it actual now, but try to update Android Strudio. After that type in the latest version of gradle in Project Structure -> in field Gradle Version. I've fixed it with 4.4 Gradle version. It may take a while (rebuilding current project by cliking "try now" and restarting studio several times), but at the end you have chance to fix that and search libraries in dependencies. Idk if it will help you, but it helped me.

Comment: After updating to Android Studio 3.1 everything begin to work properly.