# Add Library Dependency Inside Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I want to search maven central inside the android studio to find my favorite android library.(I know it could be done with a google search and add library manually in gradle). But I found a sweet option in the android studio under `Project Settings>app>Dependencies>+Add Library Dependency.` 
I found there is some library listed by default but when I search for the library it shows nothing.
For example when I typed in search field **"butterknife"** it shows nothing. Heres it is

[image: snapshot]. But I noticed in the search description it says

> Enter terms for Maven Central Search or fully qualified
>   coordinates(e.g com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4)

As far I understand it search in Maven Central. if so whats wrong with my android studio/process?

Comment: call `dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}`

Comment: it's working fine on my side. Did you got any libraries in field  (nothing to show area) before searching butterknife ?

Comment: I can confirm that butterknife appeared in the list, try invalidating cache.

Comment: @Umair yes i found some library listed by default.

Comment: @Enzokie i complied 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'  in gradle manually  and syned and its ok. that means i found there's a working network connection.

Comment: I did a test again, I keep searching 'butterknife' couple of times and sometimes the list don't show so this could be some sort of bug.

Comment: @Enzokie if its a bug then how can i submit a request to fix the bug?

Comment: Go to Help > Submit Feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169839/discussion-between-enam-and-enzokie).

Answer (score 0):

It's a **bug** in searching for libraries portion sometimes it shows sometimes it doesn't but if you will type complete name like for example in your case `'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'` then it will give you the results all the time. So try searching through giving the whole name and also it's a good idea to submit a query for bug fix.

[image]

Comment: if i know the full name of a library then this features is useless.

Comment: @Enam yes you are right, but it returns result on the base of name only sometimes. so i think we will have to live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is already resolved. Please **update Android studio with latest version 3.1** and also **update gradle with latest version 4.4**

Comment: this issue is not resolved yet, I am using latest tools and it still occurs on my side

Comment: @Umair, It's strange. Here, In my Android Studio, I can easily search library with simple name and [this another guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48222905/2264534) also resolved after new update

Comment: I have studio 3.1.2 version and latest gradle but it gives me results sometimes but not all the times.

Comment: Are you using Gradle 4.4 in your project?

Comment: yup m using Gradle 4.4